Laravel 11 RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined when accessing auth routes without login
I'm encountering an issue in my Laravel 11 application when trying to access authentication routes without being logged in. The error I am seeing is:
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [login] not defined.

I have set up the auth middleware for both the web and admin guards, and I am using separate login routes for both guards. Here’s my route setup for authentication:
// Web routes
Route::get('/web/login', [AuthController::class, 'index'])->name('web.login');
Route::post('/web/login-user', [AuthController::class, 'login']);

// Admin routes
Route::get('/admin', [AdminController::class, 'loginView'])->name('admin.login');
Route::post('/admin/loginF', [AdminController::class, 'adminLogin']);

In my config/auth.php, I have the guards and providers set up like this:
'guards' => [
'web' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'users',
],
'admin' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'admins',
],
],

'providers' => [
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\Member::class,
],
'admins' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\Admin::class,
],
],

But whenever I try to access a route that requires authentication, I get the error message: Route [login] not defined..
I’ve checked the routes file and the guards, and they seem correct. I also ensured that I have defined separate routes for admin and web login.
What am I missing here? Why is Laravel not able to find the login route?
Additional Context:
Laravel version: 11
I am using separate guards for admin and web.
The login routes are correctly named (admin.login and web.login)
I want a solution to make custom redirections here because laravel 11 don't have middleware built in

I also faced the same issue as you in the Auth system on the Laravel 11 based project I am working on right now.
In my case, this "Laravel 11 RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined when accessing auth routes without login" error happened because my auth controller system I created failed to save the auth results in the existing user session (in my case, I used SESSION_DRIVER=database) so it returned to the default user page when user not authenticated. Previously on some projects that I worked on using Laravel 10, it can be set the default page via Authenticate.php in middleware (app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php).
There's a lot of thing changed in Laravel 11 and I just found the same issue on Laravel 11 GitHub Issue https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/6274 that's worked for my problem. To set the default page when the user not authenticated is by adding some lines of code on withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {}) app.php (bootstrap/app.php) :
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))->withRouting(
   web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
   api: __DIR__ . '/../routes/api.php',
   commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
   channels: __DIR__ . '/../routes/channels.php',
   health: '/up',
)
->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
$middleware->redirectGuestsTo(fn () => route(<your route name registered in routes>));
})
->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
})->create();

Hope my solution can help with your issue, I am so sorry if I have bad grammar because English is not my first language.
